# Is there a way to combine the draw and pinchZoom interactions on mobile devices?

Tags: openlayers, draw, pinchzoom, interaction

On mobile devices use of pinchZoom could increase the usability while freehand drawing (draw interaction). Is there a way to achieve this?

I already tried to set the pinchZoom option to true when creating the draw interaction, but these options seem to be ignored.

Comment: `pinchZoom`  is one of the default interactions and is therefore enabled by default.  There is no `pinchDrag` interaction so specifying as an option will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks Mike, of course you are right (I edited my question accordingly). But it seems that the draw interaction disables pinchZoom somehow. I also tried iterating through all map interactions and call setActive(true) on pinchZoom, but this doesn‘t help either.

Comment: It seems similar to double click zoom.  Remove the draw by interaction by selecting shape type None and double click zoom works, otherwise it doesn't https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html